# Promises: Passing new Parameters to item in Chain Sequence

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I'm using the [q library for promises](https://github.com/kriskowal/q). I'm trying to chain multiple functions that return promises together in a sequence, but I want to pass new parameters in.

e.g. I want to do this pseudo-code:

```
var func1Param = 'abc';
var func2Param = 'def';
var func3Param = 'ghi';

func1(func1Param).then(func2(func2Param)).then(func3(func3Param));
```

So far to handle this, I've been doing something like the following, and then having the first function have all the parameters, and pass them on to the second function with the resolve, and so forth.
e.g.

```
var parms = { func1 : 'abc', func2: 'def', func3: 'ghi' }
func1(params).then(func2).then(func3);
```

However, this seems sloppy to pass parameters to a function that doesn't need them to get those parameters to a function that does need them.

What is the best way to do this? Every option I come up with either doesn't work, or seems kind of crazy convoluted. There has to be a simple way to do this properly.

Comment: Can you show the definition for each of the functions? The "best" way to do this really depends on what you're trying to do with the parameters.

Comment: What's wrong with the first way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand this correctly, but if you want to add default/prespecified variables to (Promise) callbacks you can use `Function.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])`

E.g.

```
function1(foo)
    .then(function2.bind(this, bar)
    .then(function3.bind(this, baz)
```

Comment: This was what I was thinking. I wish there was a standard way to bind arguments without dictating the context though.

Comment: This looks promising ;-). I'm testing it out now, thanks!

Comment: Thank-you! This works beautifully and is exactly what I was looking for. This makes everything simpler. It looks like I can even pull in the results of the last chained promise if needed (Its loaded in the last parameter).

Comment: Yes, using bind will provide the provided arguments as the first arguments to call the function with, everything else is still passed to the end.